# Drupal 7 exporting a custom profile to features

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, profile

I've created some new fields for users who register in admin/config/people/profile
since we are still building the site I want to port these out to a features module
but am completely unable to figure out how to do this? I thought it would be some
thing like Features >> [Create Feature] [Edit components] >> Variables but cannot
find my custom fields?

I named my new form Registration, and tried view sourcing and flipping through the
source with the find command but am unable to find it there either. Anyone know what
it might be called or under?

In order to unlock the profiles, I used this [Administer user profiles in Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/874026) method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you hadn't figured it out yet, you can export fields by selecting the "**Fields: field**" component when creating your view.

By the looks of your URL you're not using the latest 7.12 core version? Currently the page to manage the fields for user profiles is located at "Administer > Configuration > People > Account Settings > Manage fields" (admin/config/people/accounts/fields) page, so you may need to update...

Answer (score 2):

Did you create a profile or add the fields directly to the user entity?

With the drupal 7 fields API you don't need the profile module anymore in fact it's deprecated.  Because of that I don't think their is features support for profiles

Comment: @OP make sure you have Field UI module enabled or you will not see an option to modify fields in the UI.